# Cancel an alarm in Xamarin.forms (Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-notifications

I've read a lot about canceling notifications/alarms but I can't get it working. I set up a test where I create a alarm and immediately delete it. But it keeps firing.

Code to create / delete alarms (called 14 times with increasing notificationId):

```
public void CreateNotification(string title, string text, DateTime datetime, int notificationId)
{
    var alarmIntent = new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(NotificationAlarmReceiver));
    alarmIntent.SetAction("com.tender.droid.notification");

    alarmIntent.PutExtra("text", text);
    alarmIntent.PutExtra("title", title);
    alarmIntent.PutExtra("notificationId", notificationId);
    alarmIntent.PutExtra("millisecond", datetime.Millisecond);

    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Forms.Context, notificationId, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
    var alarmManager = (AlarmManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);

    alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, (long)datetime.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds, pendingIntent);

    DeleteNotification(notificationId);
}

public void DeleteNotification(int notificationId)
{
    var notificationManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
    notificationManager.Cancel(notificationId);

    var alarmIntent = new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(NotificationAlarmReceiver));
    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Forms.Context, notificationId, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
    var alarmManager = (AlarmManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
    pendingIntent.Cancel();
    alarmManager.Cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

Code for class NotificationAlarmReceiver:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Process = ":remote")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.tender.droid.notification" })]
public class NotificationAlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        var text = intent.GetStringExtra("text");
        var title = intent.GetStringExtra("title");
        var notificationId = intent.GetStringExtra("notificationId");

        var notIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(SplashScreen));
        var contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, notIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
        var manager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(context);

        var style = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        style.BigText(text);

        //Generate a notification with just short text and small icon, set notification elements:
        var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .SetContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.android_notification)
            .SetContentTitle(title)
            .SetContentText(text)
            .SetStyle(style)
            .SetWhen(Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis())
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification));

        // Instantiate the builder
        var notification = builder.Build();

        manager.Notify(Convert.ToInt32(notificationId), notification);
    }
}
```

Any help on this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please re phase your question, cancel the notification means? system notification, Application notification or inbuilt notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60 * 1000, alarmIntent);
instead of 
alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, (long)datetime.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds, pendingIntent);